# Binary operator error on condition

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview

I want to give condition on pickerview row, but it just giving me error. *Binary operator cannot be applied to operands*.

```swift
let viewList: [String] = ["Fixed", "Recurring"]

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (viewList[row] == 0) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly please help me

Comment: Do you want to check `row == 0`? You are comparing a string with a number right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated answer***

Try to do like this:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    fileprivate let viewList: [String] = ["Fixed", "Recurring"]
}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate
extension MyViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            print("Selected value \(viewList[row]) at row \(row)")

            if viewList[row] == "Fixed" {
                print("Fixed has been selected!")
            }
    }
}
```

The problem come from your condition, try the code below.

More information: [Apple Documentation - Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105)

Comment: var viewList : [String] = ["Fixed","Recurring"]
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return viewList.count
        }
        
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            return viewList[row]
        }
        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            
}

Comment: I have tried like how you declare the array but still it is giving same error

Comment: I m using using swift3

Comment: Ok i understand! If you want to check if user touch the first cell just do `if row == 0 { print("Touched row 0") }` but if you want to detect if user selected cell with the value "Fixed" just do `if viewList[row] == "Fixed" { print("Touched row Fixed") }` but be carful in case you need internalisation for your application.

Comment: @ShaybazSayyed If this has solved you problem, please accept the answer :)